# Best way to show static HTML+linked CSS from secure back-end using JWT?

Tags: html, css, angular, laravel, lumen

I have a set of different Angular applications all connecting to the same Laravel/Lumen back-end. I secure these applications using the Laravel/Lumen RestAPI with my own middleware to secure endpoint using JSON Web Tokens (JWT).
The RestAPI back-end expects a specific header to communicate the JWT and additional X-headers in order to raise the security somewhat. The Angular applications use an HTTP-interceptor to add these headers when necessary.

I do not use the blades-templates etc. from Laravel at all. ANgular versions are v13 and up. Lumen back-end is version 9.

Currently I am writing documentation using Markdown. Using some scripts and GitHub MD-processor this results in nice HTML+CSS. The goal is that this documentation can be integrated in my Angular applications as a kind of manual/help files.

I can of course integrate these HTML-files as a part of my Angular application, but the manuals contain information I'd like to only deliver when a authenticated is logged-in. By integrating them in the Angular application, a hacker only needs to open the application and all documentation is immediately available.

One way is to use my Lumen RestAPI back-end to serve the HTML-files. However, in the HTML-files there are links to other HTML-files, images and CSS-files that the browser will resolve. In this process of resolving it is hard to inject the extra headers for the JWT etcetera.

One solution could be to switch to using cookies, but this flies in the face of the RestAPI and JWT (-headers).

Another thought is to use an IFrame, but this will probably give the same problems of the browser resolving all the related files.

Of course I can write a complete new PHP-application to securely integrate these HTML/CSS files; no problem there, I have plenty experience in PHP. But this would mean transferring the JWT to this PHP-application. I could write a PHP-file to 'logon' using the JWT and then start a cookie based PHP-session so user-experience seems like there is no logon. However, it all sounds a bit cumbersome.

So I'm kind of stuck here for a simple solution. I'm really interested in your thoughts on this.

THanks!

Greetings Martin

Edit:
Just realised that it is impossible to make the browser open a new page and add some extra headers, e.g. for the token. So then I would have to add security information in e.g. the URL-query parameters, which feels very unsafe.